# jooq `myPojo` to `record`: `store` function is not available on the record

Tags: jooq

I am learning from the manual here: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos/#NA6504

And i'm trying to create a Record from a pojo and i don't have available the `record.store()` method, or `dslContext.executeInsert(newRecord)`.

My code looks as follows:

```kotlin
// this is created by me
data class Dummy(
    val name: String,
    val id: Long,
    val thisDoesNotExistInTheDatabaseAndThatsFineBecauseMappingToMyBusinessClassStillWorks: String?,
)

// table -> Business Object works ✅ 
dslContext.select()
.from(DummyTable.DUMMY_TABLE)
.fetch()
.into(Dummy::class.java)


// Business Object -> table does not work ❌ 
val newPojo = Dummy("string1", 1, null)
val newRecord: Record = dslContext.newRecord(DUMMY_TABLE, newPojo)
newRecord.store()    // this throws compilation error: Unresolved reference: store
dslContext.executeInsert(newRecord) // this throws compilation error: Type mismatch: inferred type is Record but TableRecord<*>! was expected
```

`DUMMY_TABLE` is generated by joooq: `open class DummyTable: TableImpl<Record>`.

From the documentation, my understanding is that `dslContext.newRecord(DUMMY_TABLE, newPojo).store()` should just work.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm not sure where to start looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using the most appropriate record type in your variable declaration:

```kotlin
// This
val newRecord: Record = dslContext.newRecord(DUMMY_TABLE, newPojo)

// ... should be this:
val newRecord: DummyTableRecord = dslContext.newRecord(DUMMY_TABLE, newPojo)

// ... or even this:
val newRecord = dslContext.newRecord(DUMMY_TABLE, newPojo)
```

In order to get the table records generated, please activate the relevant flag in your code generation configuration:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-records/

It should be enabled by default.

Comment: Unfortunately

```kotlin
// ... or even this:
val newRecord = dslContext.newRecord(DUMMY_TABLE, newPojo)
```

does not work.

Regarding 

```kotlin
// This
val newRecord: Record =
```

I added the type inferred explicitly to show what kotlin type is inferred. I don't show types generally.

Comment: `val newRecord: DummyTableRecord`

hmmm, so the generator should create these records of a table. i will try that.

Comment: In order to have the class `DummyTableRecord`, i needed to add this to the gradle plugin:  `isRecords = true`, in the `generator.generate` portion. Thanks Lukas!

Comment: @TheBestPessimist: Ah yes, that's an optional feature, though, it is enabled by default? You probably disabled it...